# Keycloak Saml adding Signature algorithm not working

Tags: java, keycloak, saml, saml-2.0

I am trying to secure my web application using Keycloak saml but while adding Signature it is not working and giving below error:

```
exception [org.opensaml.ws.message.encoder.MessageEncodingException: Encountered error 
marshalling message into its DOM representation] with root cause
    org.apache.xml.security.signature.XMLSignatureException: The requested algorithm null does not exist. Original Message was: Cannot invoke "java.lang.Class.newInstance()" because "<local3>" is null
Original Exception was java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke "java.lang.Class.newInstance()" because "<local3>" is null
        at org.apache.xml.security.algorithms.SignatureAlgorithm.<init>(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.xml.security.signature.SignedInfo.<init>(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.xml.security.signature.XMLSignature.<init>(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.xml.security.signature.XMLSignature.<init>(Unknown Source)
```

And my code creating AuthnRequest is as below:

```
protected String generateID() {
            Random r = new Random();
            return 'a' + Long.toString(Math.abs(r.nextLong()), 20) + Long.toString(Math.abs(r.nextLong()), 20);
        }
        public AuthnRequest buildRequest(String spProviderId, String acsUrl, String idpUrl) {
            /* Building Issuer object */
            
            
            IssuerBuilder issuerBuilder = new IssuerBuilder();
            Issuer issuer = issuerBuilder.buildObject("urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:assertion", "Issuer", "saml2");
            issuer.setValue(spProviderId);

            /* Creation of AuthRequestObject */
            DateTime issueInstant = new DateTime();
            AuthnRequestBuilder authRequestBuilder = new AuthnRequestBuilder();

            AuthnRequest authRequest = authRequestBuilder.buildObject(SAMLConstants.SAML20P_NS, "AuthnRequest", "saml2");
            authRequest.setForceAuthn(false);
            authRequest.setIssueInstant(issueInstant);
            authRequest.setProtocolBinding(SAMLConstants.SAML2_POST_BINDING_URI);
            authRequest.setAssertionConsumerServiceURL(acsUrl);
            authRequest.setIssuer(issuer);
            authRequest.setID(generateID());
            // XXX: How do I get nameIdPolicy?
//          authRequest.setNameIDPolicy(nameIdPolicy);
            authRequest.setVersion(SAMLVersion.VERSION_20);
            authRequest.setDestination(idpUrl);
            
            SignatureBuilder signFactory = new SignatureBuilder();
            Signature signature = signFactory.buildObject(Signature.DEFAULT_ELEMENT_NAME);
                    try {
                        signature.setSigningCredential(this.getSenderSigningCredential());
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
        // set signature
                    authRequest.setSignature(signature);
            

            return authRequest;
        }
```

And while encoding and generating redirect url I am getting error and it's code is as below:

```
private static class MessageEncoder extends HTTPRedirectDeflateEncoder {
        public String encode(SAMLObject message, String endpointURL, String relayState) throws MessageEncodingException {
            String encodedMessage = deflateAndBase64Encode(message);
            return buildRedirectURL(endpointURL, relayState, encodedMessage);
        }

        public String buildRedirectURL(String endpointURL, String relayState, String message) throws MessageEncodingException {
            URLBuilder urlBuilder = new URLBuilder(endpointURL);
            List<Pair<String, String>> queryParams = urlBuilder.getQueryParams();
            queryParams.clear();
            queryParams.add(new Pair<String, String>("SAMLRequest", message));
            if (checkRelayState(relayState)) {
                queryParams.add(new Pair<String, String>("RelayState", relayState));
            }
            return urlBuilder.buildURL();
        }
    }
```

I am getting credential from "jks" file. What mistake am I making, or what configuration is missing?